# A trigonometry question involving medians and a sum of cotangents

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The medians of a triangle $ABC$ make angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ with each other. I have to prove that:

> $$\cot\alpha+ \cot\beta+ \cot\gamma +\cot(A)+\cot(B)+\cot(C)= 0.$$

Any ideas?

Comment: i tried using mn cot theorem....i know median AD makes angles cotx = 2cotA+cotC. coty=2cotA+cotB

Answer (score 1):

[image]

By the sine and cosine theorems,

$$\cot(\widehat{BGC}) = \frac{\cos\widehat{BGC}}{\sin\widehat{BGC}} = \frac{\frac{BG^2+CG^2-BC^2}{2\, BG\cdot CG}}{\frac{2[BGC]}{BG\cdot CG}}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{BG^2+CG^2-BC^2}{[BGC]}\tag{1}$$
but $BG=\frac{2}{3}m_a$ and Stewart's theorem gives $m_a^2 = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}$, hence:
$$\cot(\widehat{BGC}) = \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{BG^2+CG^2-BC^2}{[ABC]} = \frac{b^2+c^2-5a^2}{12[ABC]}\tag{2}.$$
On the other hand,
$$ \cot(\widehat{BAC}) = \frac{\cos\widehat{BAC}}{\sin\widehat{BAC}}=\frac{\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2\,AB\cdot AC}}{\frac{2[ABC]}{AB\cdot AC}}=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4[ABC]}\tag{3}$$
hence:
$$ \cot A+\cot B+\cot C = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4[ABC]} = -\left(\cot\alpha+\cot\beta+\cot\gamma\right)\tag{4} $$
as wanted.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the $100K$ mark ! :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian: thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $BC=a, CA=b, BA=c$, $m_a, m_b, m_c$ and $G$ be the medians and centroid of $\Delta ABC$. Let $[ABC] = \Delta$, then it is clear that $$[BGC]=[CGA]=[AGB]=\frac{\Delta}{3}.$$

Now, note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc} {\cot A} &= \sum_{cyc} {\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}} \\
&= \sum_{cyc} {\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\cdot \frac{bc}{2\Delta} \right)} \\
&= \sum_{cyc} {\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4\Delta}} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4\Delta}}
\end{align*}

Now, apply Law of Cosines on $\Delta BGC$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\cos \alpha &= \frac{BG^2+CG^2-BC^2}{2\cdot BG\cdot CG} \\
&= \frac{{\frac{4}{9}m_b}^2 + \frac{4}{9}m_c^2 -a^2}{2\cdot \frac{2}{3}m_b\cdot \frac{2}{3}m_c} \\
&= \frac{b^2+c^2-5a^2}{8m_bm_c}
\end{align*}

Again, in $\Delta BGC$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sin \alpha &= \frac{2[BGC]}{BG\cdot CG} \\
&= \frac{3\Delta}{2m_bm_c}
\end{align*}

We obtain analogous expressions for $\cos \beta, \cos \gamma, \sin \beta$ and $\sin \gamma.$

\begin{align*}
\therefore \sum_{cyc} {\cot \alpha} &= \sum_{cyc} {\frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}} \\
&= \sum_{cyc} {\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-5a^2}{8m_bm_c}\cdot \frac{2m_bm_c}{3\Delta}\right)} \\
&= \sum_{cyc} {\frac{b^2+c^2-5a^2}{12\Delta}} \\
&= \boxed{-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4\Delta}}
\end{align*}

Hence, $\boxed{\cot A+\cot B+\cot C+\cot \alpha+\cot \beta+\cot \gamma = 0\;}.$
$QED.$